# Chosen jQuery plugin not functional.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Using Chosen version 1.0.0
I included the following files

```
link(href='css/chosen.css', rel="stylesheet", type="text/css");
script(src='js/chosen.jquery.min.js')
script.
    $(".chosen-select").chosen()

body
  select(data-placeholder="Choose a country...", multiple style="width:350px;" ).chosen-select
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
```

The above code gives a disfunctional `select box` The above display is same as

```
select(multiple, style="width:350px;")
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
```

Upon analysis I see, that both `chosen.css` and `chosen.jquery.min.js` have no class `chosen-select` I am using jQuery version `v1.10.2` Also I am loading jQuery as the first file on the page to avoid conflict.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding

```
script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".chosen-select").chosen()
        });
```

Instead of just `$(".chosen-select").chosen()` makes it work!

Answer (score 0):

Mine doesn't worked instead it worked by

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chosen.jquery.js" >
</script>   
<script>
    `Enter only enter chosen related code here`
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happened because the confliction of the jquery library.
Define your JavaScript inside no conflict.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/