# TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'chosen' in IE10 / IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer gives error that it does not support chosen method or property.It work fine in chrome and firefox. Is there any alternate to this.. 
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'chosen'
   at Anonymous function (eval code:37:17)
   at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js?_=1417526805748:2:27128)

```
function setFocusOnLoad() {}    // This will disable the auto opening of the Select List when page loads.
            $(document).ready(function(){
            // Dynamically create the Select List and options
            var select = $('<select class="selectDiv" id="selectPickList{!Unique}" multiple>');

            var hasAllOption{!Unique}       = {!All};
            var hasAllByDefault{!Unique}    = {!All_Default};
            var allName{!Unique}            = '{!All_Name}';
            //alert('hi');
            if(allName{!Unique} == '')
                allName{!Unique} = 'None Selected';   


            if(hasAllOption{!Unique}){
                if(hasAllByDefault{!Unique})
                    select.append('<option value="" selected>'+allName{!Unique}+'</option>');        
                else
                    select.append('<option value="" selected>'+allName{!Unique}+'</option>'); 
            }

            <apex:repeat value="{!Picklist}" var="p">
                select.append('<option value="{!p}" >{!Picklist[p]}</option>');

            </apex:repeat>
            var selSize = $('select[id^="selectPickList{!Unique}"]');
            if(selSize.length == 0){
                $('#selectDiv{!Unique}').append(select);
            }
            var width{!Unique}  = '{!width}';
            if(width{!Unique} == '')
                    width{!Unique} = '50%'; // default is 50%

            // Initialize the chosen for every Component used. Uniqueness is very important 
            var chosen{!Unique} = $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").chosen({
                  no_results_text: "No results matched",
                  create_option: false,
                  width: width{!Unique},
                  placeholder_text_multiple: "Select or Search.."
            });

            // Add the change event. 

            $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").on('change', function(evt, params) {

                if(params.selected == ''){ // if All is selected remove the rest

                    var arrVals = $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").val(); 

                    arrVals = [''];

                    $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").val(arrVals);

                    chosen{!Unique}.trigger("chosen:updated");



                }else{ // If something else is selected remove the All. So the ALL & Rest is mutually exclusive


                    var arrVals = $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").val();                        
                    for(var i=0;i<arrVals.length;i++){
                        if(arrVals[i] == ''){
                            arrVals.splice(i,1);
                        }
                    }
                    $("#selectPickList{!Unique}").val(arrVals);
                    chosen{!Unique}.trigger("chosen:updated");

                }

                selected{!Unique} = $('#selectPickList{!Unique}').val(); // Set this for using from Visualforce page
                if('{!Page_Element_Id}' != '')
                    document.getElementById("{!Page_Element_Id}").value = selected{!Unique};
            });

            var selected{!Unique} = $('#selectPickList{!Unique}').val(); // Very important variable. that can used from a visualforce page. 
            if('{!Page_Element_Id}' != '')
                    document.getElementById("{!Page_Element_Id}").value = selected{!Unique};
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chosen jQuery plugin not functional.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568782/chosen-jquery-plugin-not-functional)

Comment: Showing serverside/templated JS code does no help with debugging and what is "chosen"?

Comment: No @DylanCorriveau This is not the solution . Actually it working in chrome and firefox , but in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 .

Comment: @epascarello chosen in jQuery plugin. According to them it should work about IE9 but it is not working..  Any idea

Comment: [This page](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/335) suggests that this issue occurs when using compatibility view. Are you using compatibility view?

Comment: Hi @JLRishe I don't thing that might be the issue.

Comment: Hi @JLRishe I tried but it did not work out.